# In the CVPR16 paper "Deepbit" by Kevin Lin, et al, is it a typo in the loss function section?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, loss-function

Recently I'm researching through possible ways of encoding images into compact binary descriptors that allows for fast image matching in a large corpus and came across [this paper](http://www.iis.sinica.edu.tw/~kevinlin311.tw/cvpr16-deepbit.pdf) written by Kevin Lin and his colleagues.

In the article, they proposed an unsupervised learning approach to learn compact binary descriptors for images. Specifically, they proposed a loss function to penalize the descriptor that consists of 3 components:

1. quantization loss
2. even distribution loss
3. bits correlation loss

My question lies in the first component. In the paper, the loss function is defined as the sum of the squared error between the binary bit and the last layer's activation across all the training data in the mini-batch. However, when I implement this, the overall loss became so large that the other 2 components became somewhat irrelevant and therefore not evenly distributed at all.

So I'm wondering if this is a typo in the paper where it should be the mean of the squared error instead of the sum.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: This is an off-topic question, but since all equations in the paper are *numbered*, it wouldn't hurt to indicate exactly which one you refer to...

Comment: I'm referring to the (5) equation in the paper, shouldn't there be a "1/N" before the summation? I understand that this question is not exactly about programming directly, but it will affect how I implement the loss function in my program. By the way, I wonder if there's something similar to StackOverflow that's for scientific papers, preferably in the domain of machine learning?

Comment: 1) pls edit & update your post regarding this clarification 2) not specifically for scientific papers, but there are three (3) Stack Exchange fora dedicated to such issues, namely [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), and [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/)